# Azure SQL Database - Measure Data by User

Tags: azure-sql-database

I'm setting up an Azure SQL Database with multiple user logins.

Is there any way for me to view a breakdown of the total amount of data consumed by user for a given period?

Comment: Are these multiple users accessing shared data or does the data belong to them?

Answer (score 2):

If you can consider having a separate schema for each user, you can easily measure the size of each schema. I guess you are asking this for billing purposes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: True, but you could have clients with a smaller amount of data making more requests.  Ideally I'd want to know how much data they consumed for the period.

Comment: Look at the billing samples in the following URL https://github.com/Azure-Samples/billing-dotnet-usage-api